# Wait for all responses, then call the function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have multiple URLs to call data from and I want to call a function after they have all responded and the data has been received.

```
var promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
 
Promise.all(promises).then(response => {
 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  response[i].json().then(data => { dataReceived.push(data.rows)})
 }
 }).then(dataReceived=> {

  doThisFucntion(withAllTheData);
  
 });
```

I'm Sure I just need to add another `promise.all()` but I have no idea where to do that.

Comment: Do your first set of promises get a response that you want to load images with or  do something Asynchronous? If not, you don't need any more promises, after the first group is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need another `Promise.all`. Just put the body parsing and property extraction promise chaining in the `map` callback that you already have:

```
var promises = urls.map(url =>
  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => data.rows)
);

Promise.all(promises).then(doThisFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this one:

```
var promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url));

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(response => Promise.all(response.map(resp=>resp.json())))
  .then(data=>data.map(element=>element.rows))
  .then(dataReceived=> {    
    doThisFucntion(withAllTheData);
  });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the same trick you used for the urls. Just take each response, map it to what you want, and put all that in a `Promise.all`:

```
var promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url));

Promise.all(promises).then(response => {
    return Promise.all(response.map(resp => resp.json().then(data => data.rows)));
}).then(dataReceived => {
    // dataReceived is an array where each entry is one of the 'data.rows' from before.
    doThisFucntion(dataReceived);
});
```